# How do you set the value of a key, in a hash, to the difference of the values of two other keys?

Tags: ruby, hash

I would like to set the value of "vars['dif']" to the difference of the values of "globalvars['days']" and "globalvars['supplies']" (set the value of 'dif' to 'days' - 'supplies')

Any answer that tells me how to do this would be helpful even if it means I need to change my code compleatly, but I would prefer it done in a way I can keep my code.

```
globalvars = { 'days' => 0 , 'supplies' => 0 }

puts "Please input the number of days the trip will take."
globalvars['days'] = gets.chomp
puts "Please input the number of days worth of supplies each person can carry."
globalvars['supplies'] = gets.chomp
puts globalvars

puts ;
puts "Press RETURN to continue."
gets


if (globalvars['days'] <= globalvars['supplies'])
    then
    puts "No helpers are needed."
    puts "Press RETURN to continue."
    gets
else
    puts "Helpers are needed."
    puts "Press RETURN to continue."
    gets
end


vars = { 'man' => 0 , 'varx' => 0 , 'dif' => 0 }
vars['man'] = globalvars['supplies']
vars['dif'] = globalvars['days'] - globalvars['supplies'] "< this is the line"

puts vars


puts ;
puts "Press RETURN to exit."
gets
```

If anyone knows how to make the gets command only accept a certain key, e.g. enter, to be pressed please add that to your answer.

Comment: What's the problem with `globalvars['days'] - globalvars['supplies']`?

Comment: Your Hash values are Strings. Convert them to integers. eg:  `globalvars['days'] = gets.chomp.to_i`

Comment: @Santhosh thanks that fixed it!

Comment: @DracoAter I had used that code originally and it wasn't working turns out I just did the gets wrong. Thanks though.